# greater than is not working in SOLR filter query

Tags: solr

I write up the solr query to extract the items which hits greater than 610. but it is displaying all the docs in the solr core instead if listing the items which hits > 610.

kindly find the below url and guide me.

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mainitemdata/select?q=*%3A*&fq=hitsSort%3A+610+To+*&wt=xml&indent=true
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this (with capital TO and square brackets) :

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mainitemdata/select?q=*%3A*&fq=hitsSort%3A%5B610+TO+*%5D&wt=xml&indent=true
```

You can look [this page](https://wiki.apache.org/solr/SolrQuerySyntax#Differences_From_Lucene_Query_Parser) for range query.

Answer (score 1):

Try capital TO:

```
http://localhost:8983/solr/mainitemdata/select?q=*%3A*&fq=hitsSort[610 TO *]&wt=xml&indent=true
```